# How to restore color in css after mouse leave?

Tags: css

When I click on the button in my header it changes the color to #699fca (as expected). But when mouse leaves the button the color changes to gray. I want to get it 699fca (not gray).

Here is my example: jsfiddle.net/93b62qLf/1

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add css for the `visited` state of the link, which is what is applied after it has been clicked. Something like this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:visited {
    background-color: #699fca;
}
```